# rails_admin show all field in list except one field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, field, rails-admin

In rails_admin gem i have a model with some field.
In list action is possible to view all field except one field? 
if i write:

```
rails_admin do
 list do
   field :name
 end
end
```

I see only this field, i need the inverse behavior. I have found no solutions

```
#somethis like this
rails_admin do
 list do
   field :default , except :created_at
 end
end
```

can you help me?

A possible workaround is list all necessary field, but is not very clean in my opinion

***SOLUTION***
this works for me:

```
list do
      exclude_fields :created_at
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Once in add specified fields mode, you can exclude some specific fields with exclude_fields & exclude_fields_if:"

https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#exclusion

example:

```
rails_admin do
 list do
   field :default
 end

   exclude_fields :created_at
end
```

Comment: You don't need the 'list' block: just 'rails_admin do exclude_fields :created_at end' is enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is *ruby* - use it!

```
rails_admin do
  list do
    (column_names - %w{created_at}).each do |col_name|
      field col_name.to_sym
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can just use the `exclude_fields` macro as @flylib has pointed out. ;)